Flatten JSON data from Telegraf to use in ThingsBoard
I am connected to ThingsBoard and Telegraf to visualize my CPU usage, but the data received is in nested JSON format. I have tried different ways to achieve it, but I am unable to get the data in flattened JSON format.
Using Telegraf version 1.30.0, the data is returned in this format:
[
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":91.40585349348385,
    "usage_iowait":0.1691761123329754,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.13534088986632262,
    "usage_softirq":0.08458805616646366,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":2.317712738961436,
    "usage_user":5.887328709186236
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":91.94207836457213,
    "usage_iowait":0.9028960817717189,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.30664395229985647,
    "usage_softirq":0.11925042589437249,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.8568994889266988,
    "usage_user":4.872231686542196
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":91.22272957889072,
    "usage_iowait":0.8963301200743917,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.35514967021814886,
    "usage_softirq":0.05073566717402127,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":2.130898021308797,
    "usage_user":5.344156942329791
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":92.3648648648699,
    "usage_iowait":0.4222972972973181,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.3209459459459579,
    "usage_softirq":0.05067567567566809,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.2837837837838315,
    "usage_user":5.557432432432644
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":92.40399255626502,
    "usage_iowait":0.16917611233301705,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.11842327863312155,
    "usage_softirq":0.033835222466601006,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.3364912874308539,
    "usage_user":5.938081542887148
    },
  "name":"cpu4",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":92.9369918699103,
    "usage_iowait":0.5928184281842386,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.16937669376690467,
    "usage_softirq":0.016937669376688058,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.1856368563684772,
    "usage_user":5.09823848238449
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":93.07888040712137,
    "usage_iowait":0.25445292620872184,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.15267175572520417,
    "usage_softirq":0.06785411365564227,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.5436810856660335,
    "usage_user":4.902459711620043
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":92.3622845555872,
    "usage_iowait":0.33795201081445,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.15207840486649526,
    "usage_softirq":0.03379520108144139,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.824940858397751,
    "usage_user":5.288948969245875
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
},
{
  "fields":{
    "usage_guest":0,
    "usage_guest_nice":0,
    "usage_idle":92.21845893310595,
    "usage_iowait":0.4678238780693211,
    "usage_irq":0,
    "usage_nice":0.21168501270109033,
    "usage_softirq":0.05503810330228156,
    "usage_steal":0,
    "usage_system":1.682895850973822,
    "usage_user":5.364098221845659
    },
  "name":"yavar",
  "tags":{},
  "timestamp":1716900420
}
]

but I need the data in the flattened JSON format from Telegraf to ThingsBoard.

Could you please specify the destination format, not just flattened JSON. A good startingpoint for JSON operations is jq.

@Nithish kumar B It is unclear how or where do you get data from Telegraf. In general, you can reformat incoming data in Rule Engine using Transformation Script node.
